# Get MouseCursor-Movement/Position while moving physical Mouse while Cursor is at ScreenBoundary

Tags: c#, wpf, cursor, mouse

Community

for my current project (C#, WPF, VS 16.5.3, W10 1909), I need to recognize Mouse-Movement, even if the cursor is at a screen-border (i.e. top-right) and the user continues moving the mouse.
When I ask for the position by

```
Mouse.GetPosition(Application.Current.MainWindow)
```

I get the position within the screen and the values stop changing if I continue moving the physical mouse while the cursor is at a screen-border. What I would like was an "virtual infinite screen" from which I would get the coordinates of the mouse-cursor (other ideas are welcome as well).
How do I achieve that?

Thx

Answer (score 1):

```
    using System;
    using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

    namespace StackOverFlow
    {
        public class Program
        {
            [DllImport("user32.dll")]
            static extern bool GetCursorPos(out POINT lpPoint);

            public struct POINT
            {
                public int X;
                public int Y;
            }

            static int _x, _y;

            static void ShowMousePosition()
            {
                POINT point;
                if (GetCursorPos(out point) && point.X != _x && point.Y != _y)
                {
                    Console.Clear();
                    Console.WriteLine("({0},{1})", point.X, point.Y);
                    _x = point.X;
                    _y = point.Y;
                }
            }

            static void Main()
            {
                while (true)
                {
                    ShowMousePosition();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your effort. Unfortunately, this achieves the same result as I've allready had: it works outside the window, but not outside screen boundaries. Besides as a hint for you: you can get the same result easier than with your code with two lines: Application.Current.MainWindow.CaptureMouse(); Point mousPosition = Mouse.GetPosition(Application.Current.MainWindow);

Comment: You pointed me into the direction of a decent workaround: after moving the mousecursor for a few pixels, i will reset the cursor to the initial position and measure the travelling distance. For THIS application, it does not hurt the user experience because the cursor is invisible. I cannot mark your answer as correct, but I will upvote it anyway.